# How to get sum/expenditure in salary with minimum query

Tags: mysql

Hi here is the sql statement in mySql.

Can any body suggest best mySql statement for the following.

> SELECT A.id, A.salary, A.salary+ IFNULL((SELECT SUM(B.salary) FROM test_salary B WHERE B.id <  A.id ORDER BY id DESC),0) AS tot FROM  test_salary A

How many times this query runs? 
- number of rows available is table + 1.

> I want result like this:
>   id  salary  tot
>   1   200  200
>   2   300  500
>   3   400  900
>   4   500  1400
>   5   600  2000
>   6   700  2700
>   7   800  3500
>   8   900  4400

- where salary table has only id and salary field.

Comment: Please put more effort into your English, it's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: Hi, please check it again and reply.

Comment: Ok so your query works but you are worried about performance. Please have a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from what you are trying to do here but the following is at least syntactically correct.

```
SELECT A.id, A.salary, 
       A.salary+IFNULL((SELECT SUM(B.salary) FROM test_salary B WHERE B.id = a.id),0)
from a
```

Based on your edit I can see that your query works. The sub query will run for every row encountered in your main query. An alternative is to use a variable

```
select a.id,a.salary,
         @tot := @tot + a.salary as tot
from test_salary a, (select @tot:=0) t;
```

I suggest you compare your query to this for performance.

Comment: > I want result like this:
id salary tot
1 200 200
2 300 500
3 400 900
4 500 1400
5 600 2000
6 700 2700
7 800 3500
8 900 4400 
- where salary table has only id and salary field.

Comment: Great it would really help you if you added sample data and expected result to your question (as text). BTW there is no salary table in your data only a and b.